# Combinatorics and Graph Theory - The $1$'s and $0$'s Circle Problem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm taking a combinatorics and graph theory course. Can anyone explain to me the "$1's$ and $0's$ circle problem"? I can't seem to find anything online about it...

The basic premise is that you have $2^n-1\;\;$  $0's$ and $2^n-1\;\;$ $1's$ and you put them in a circle. Can someone please walk me through a basic "$1's$ and $0's$ circle problem"? And links to online references are greatly appreciated as well!

Comment: [Necklaces with equal numbers of two coloured beads](//oeis.org/A003239)?

Comment: Found out what it is... it's finding the de Bruijn sequence when you have an equal number of 1's and 0's. Thanks though Pete, that was definitely in the same arena.

Good post on de Bruign sequence:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/de-bruijn-sequence-set-1/